# Multiple fields have the same columnName Android Room

Tags: mysql, android-room, pojo

I have 3 tables ruser, accounts, accountgroup. Each one has a same column called rsuerId.

I created a POJO class with 3 Embedded objects as below.

```
class GroupChatItem(
    @Embedded
    val rUserDto: RUserDto,
    @Embedded
    val account: AccountDto,
    @Embedded
    val accountGroup: AccountGroupDto
)
```

Now, i want to make a query that fetches a GroupChatItem with a given rUserId and accountGroupId like the following.

```
@Query("""
        Select ruser.*, accounts.*, accountgroup.*
        from ruser 
        inner join accounts on accounts.rUserId = ruser.rUserId and accounts.active = 1 
        inner join accountgroup on accountgroup.rUserId = :rUserId and accountGroup.accountGroupId = :accountGroupId
        where ruser.rUserId = :rUserId
    """)
    suspend fun getGroupChatItem(rUserId: Long, accountGroupId: Int): GroupChatItem
```

Unfortunately i get the following error.

```
 Multiple fields have the same columnName: rUserId. Field names: rUserDto > rUserId, account > rUserId, accountGroup > rUserId.
```

I have tried to add a prefix to each embedded object but i get also an error. I dont want to retrieve columns one-by-one because there are many of them.
Is there anything that i missed...??
Thank you

Comment: Nope, you need to retrieve them one by one, using `select *` in production code is generally considered poor practice.

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear to you?  You have more than one column that has the same name.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use the [prefix attribute](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Embedded#prefix()) of the Embedded anotation:

```java
class GroupChatItem(
    @Embedded(prefix = "user_")
    val rUserDto: RUserDto,
    @Embedded(prefix = "acc_")
    val account: AccountDto,
    @Embedded(prefix = "accgr_")
    val accountGroup: AccountGroupDto
)
```

and then alias all the columns of each entity in your SQL query.

I think the prefix attribute is s recent update but I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you have any option other than to have/use :-

- a) have distinct columns names across the tables that are to be included in joins (then there is no need to prefix the column names),

or

- b) to rename the columns using AS when extracting the values along with a prefix when embedding the entity ensuring that the names match.

I believe that a) would be the simpler option as there is a reduction in the chance of inadvertently using the wrong column name.

---

As I understand it, the column names have to match for Room to be able to know how to be able to copy a value from the underlying result set, which has no indication of what table a value came from to the value in the returned object or objects.

This is an example of the generated code of a similar scenario 3 embedded entities (**User**, **Office** and **Places**) where some of the column names are the same. They each have and **id** column and User and Places both have a columns named **name**.

```
@Override
public UserOfficePlacesCombined getAllUserOfficePlacesCombined() {
    final String _sql = "SELECT user.id AS userid, user.name AS username, office.id AS officeid, office.address AS officeaddress, places.id AS placesid, places.name AS placesname FROM User JOIN Office ON User.id = Office.id JOIN Places ON User.id = Places.id";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 0);
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, _statement, false, null);
    try {
        final int _cursorIndexOfId = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "userid");
        final int _cursorIndexOfName = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "username");
        final int _cursorIndexOfId_1 = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "officeid");
        final int _cursorIndexOfAddress = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "officeaddress");
        final int _cursorIndexOfId_2 = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "placesid");
        final int _cursorIndexOfName_1 = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "placesname");
        final UserOfficePlacesCombined _result;
        if(_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final User _tmpUser;
            if (! (_cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfId) && _cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfName))) {
                final long _tmpId;
                _tmpId = _cursor.getLong(_cursorIndexOfId);
                final String _tmpName;
                _tmpName = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfName);
                _tmpUser = new User(_tmpId,_tmpName);
            }  else  {
                _tmpUser = null;
            }
            final Office _tmpOffice;
            if (! (_cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfId_1) && _cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfAddress))) {
                final long _tmpId_1;
                _tmpId_1 = _cursor.getLong(_cursorIndexOfId_1);
                final String _tmpAddress;
                _tmpAddress = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfAddress);
                _tmpOffice = new Office(_tmpId_1,_tmpAddress);
            }  else  {
                _tmpOffice = null;
            }
            final Places _tmpPlaces;
            if (! (_cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfId_2) && _cursor.isNull(_cursorIndexOfName_1))) {
                final long _tmpId_2;
                _tmpId_2 = _cursor.getLong(_cursorIndexOfId_2);
                final String _tmpName_1;
                _tmpName_1 = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfName_1);
                _tmpPlaces = new Places(_tmpId_2,_tmpName_1);
            }  else  {
                _tmpPlaces = null;
            }
            _result = new UserOfficePlacesCombined();
            _result.setUser(_tmpUser);
            _result.setOffice(_tmpOffice);
            _result.setPlaces(_tmpPlaces);
        } else {
            _result = null;
        }
        return _result;
    } finally {
        _cursor.close();
        _statement.release();
    }
}
```

The critical lines are the ones like :-

```
 final int _cursorIndexOfId = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "userid")
```

This is used to search for the column's names in the Cursor (aka result set) and return the offset to the column, the index then being used to get the actual value from the Cursor.

In your scenario the result set will include some like

- rUserId    rUserId   rUserId*

Which one should it use for which? You may know/understand that first is ruser.rUserId, and that the second is account.rUserId and that the third is accountgroup.rUserId but Room, as it stands, will not know when generating the code. So in all 3 instances when `getColumnIndex("rUserId")` is used, it will return either 0 (the first) it breaks out of the loop, or 2 if it continues rather than breaks out of the loop (I believe it doesn't break out of the loop).

Comment: The problem with _trying_ to have distinct column names across tables, is they usually end up being made distinct by tacking on the prefixes trying to be avoided; then the db grows and the prefix is relevant to multiple tables, so then you have to remember which table used which prefix, and eventually end up having to qualify the names with the tables/aliases you were originally trying to avoid, so queries end up looking like `....runbigdata AS rbg JOIN runbaddata AS rbd ON rbg.rbdvalue = rbd.rbdvalue....`

Comment: @Uueerdo I am not getting into a discussion of whether or not to support poor design or not. If you believe that poor design should be accommodated by Room then please speak to those responsible for Room.

Comment: Well is there any way that i can exclude specific columns from the query...?

Comment: @james04 You can exclude columns by specifically including the other columns but you may then have issues with the underlying objects not being able to be generated.